# Create a method that convert a List<SObject> to a Map<SObjectField, SObject> with SObjectField as method parameter, any suggestions?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

```
global with sharing class test1 {
global Map<SObjectField, SObject> ConvertMap(List<SObject> listToConvert){
    List<SObject> listToConvert = new List<SObject>;
    Map<SObjectField, SObject> mapTest = new Map<SObjectField, SObject>;
    mapTest.putAll(listToConvert);
    return mapTest;
}
```

I've written this code, but it doesn't respect the request 'cause I can't put SObjectField as method parameter since the Map won't recognize the variable.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've tagged this as "oracle-apex". That is an oracle product not related to the salesforce product with the same name.

Comment: Can you show what your code looks like with SObjectField as a parameter and how you are calling this method? 
There are a couple of issues with the given code:
1. `listToConvert`- there is a parameter and a method variable by the same name.
2. putAll method is only going to create a  `Map<ID, sObject>`, not a map with any other field as key. You will have to iterate over the list and add each record individually to the map with the required key

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need `SobjectField` as map keys? the special class? If you're fine with strings as keys then there's a builtin, [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap)

If you absolutely need SobjectField (I don't even know if it's serializable and can be passed to integrations, LWC etc)... You'd have to loop and marry the results to something like

`Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Account'})[0].fields.getMap()`